# Version mismatch : Ubuntu 12.04 got installed with Linux 3.5 kernel

Tags: 12.04, versions

I downloaded wubi.exe from the [NZ mirror](http://nz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-releases/precise/).  See the file at the bottom of this page

The installation worked fine and I am running Ubuntu now.
But it seems to have installed Ubuntu 12.04 with headers for Linux kernel 3.5 (instead of 3.2)

Furthermore, when I tried `apt-get install linux-source`, it installed kernel source for 3.2.

Output of various commands is seen below.

Can anyone shed light on what might have contributed to this version mismatch ?

```
$ lsb_release -a

No LSB modules are available.

Distributor ID :Ubuntu
Description    :Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS
Release        :12.04
Codename       :precise
```

`$ uname -a` (says 3.5 is running)

```
Linux ubuntu 3.5.0-25-generic #39~precise1-Ubuntu SMP Tue Feb 26 00:07:14 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux


$ cat /proc/version

Linux ubuntu 3.5.0-25-generic #39~precise1-Ubuntu SMP Tue Feb 26 00:07:14 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

(Linux headers for 3.5 got installed during normal installation; later I did apt-get for the linux-source and it downloaded source for 3.2 as seen below)

```
$ ls -l /usr/src
```

total 3

```
drwxr-xr-x 24 root root 1024 Mar 16 04:12 linux-headers-3.5.0-25

drwxr-xr-x  7 root root 1024 Mar 16 04:12 linux-headers-3.5.0-25-generic

drwxr-xr-x 26 root root 1024 Mar 16 16:06 linux-source-3.2.0

lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root   45 Feb 19 18:57 linux-source-3.2.0.tar.bz2 -> linux-source-3.2.0/linux-source-3.2.0.tar.bz2
```

Also, `cat /usr/include/linux/version.h` shows `\#define LINUX_VERSION_CODE 197157`

Comment: See this blogpost by @JorgeCastro: http://www.jorgecastro.org/2013/02/19/what-the-lts-enablement-stack-means-for-sysadmins/